# Converting xml data to JSON

Tags: javascript, web-services, wcf

How can I convert XML data to JSON.
I have service which gives XML data to client javascript. How can I convert it to json object for rendering it to client.
My javascript directly calls services to get data and render it on html page.

Comment: Have you tried the Jenkins documentation?

Comment: I have to change question.

Comment: If you are getting the response from WCF service, you can change the response type to get json data directly.

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 My WCF service is third party service provider so it is fixed. I can't change its response and I have to use xml.

Comment: You can check here for converting XML 2 Json and viceversa in clientside using javascript
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html

Comment: This is not a changed question, this is a completely **new** question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConvertXmlToJson.htm

```
string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' standalone='no'?>
 <root>
  <person id='1'>
  <name>Alan</name>
  <url>http://www.google.com</url>
  </person>
  <person id='2'>
  <name>Louis</name>
  <url>http://www.yahoo.com</url>
  </person>
</root>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```